# Why offset change, the result is same?

Tags: mysql

When I execute query

```
select * from broker_commission_rate 
where broker_commission_rate.deleted_at is null 
order by settlement_at asc limit 20 offset 520
```

I got result start with id `560`, end with id `584`.

When I change offset from 520 to 540, I got **same** result set.

```
select * from broker_commission_rate 
where broker_commission_rate.deleted_at is null 
order by settlement_at asc limit 20 offset 540
```

Change order by clause to `order by settlement_at asc,id asc`, the result set has changed.

*I want to know why offset doesn't work in this SQL? Thank you in advance.*

---

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `broker_commission_rate` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sn` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `broker_uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `broker_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `broker_level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `employee_id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `rate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' ,
  `broker_price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00' ,
  `settlement_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `broker_commission_rate_sn_index` (`sn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

System info:

Mysql 5.6.20 @ Linux x85_64

Answer (score 1):

**Offset works actually!**

As you said when you change order by clause it returns accurate dataset. It means your order by condition was incorrect.

You were sorting by `settlement_at`, there may be duplicate values in this column so when you added another condition sort by `id`. It worked fine.

**It runs like:** If `settlement_at` is same, look for `id` to sort.

So your final query should be:

```
select * 
from broker_commission_rate 
where broker_commission_rate.deleted_at is null 
order by settlement_at asc, id asc 
limit 20 offset 540
```

Comment: How mysql calculate the offset? get the result set, then get 20 records from 520(count by number)? Why offset 520 is same with 540?

Comment: Add some data to your question so I can check it out.